# Integrating and working with .pkpass passes in Xamarin Android app

Tags: android, json, xamarin, passbook

I'm developing a Xamarin Android app and I need the ability to be able to work with Passes (PassKit passes for example (JSON)). I need to be able to list all the passes in a ListVew and be able to open and display the pass. Also be able to save them to a wallet such as PassWallet or Pass2u. I don't need the ability to create them, just view them, and save them to a wallet or discard them.

There seems to be an example Xamarin iOS app which does exactly what i need [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/PassKit/) but of course I need to be able to do this in Xamarin Android.

I've been researching this for hours but don't know how to achieve what i need. JSON.net seems the way to go to read the passes, but that's as far as I've managed to get. Some examples would be great. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

To add the pass into PassWallet you can use the following:

```
private static boolean launchPassWallet(Context applicationContext, Uri uri, boolean launchGooglePlay) {
    if (null != applicationContext) {
        PackageManager packageManager = applicationContext.getPackageManager();
        if (null != packageManager) {
            final String strPackageName = "com.attidomobile.passwallet";
            Intent startIntent = new Intent();
            startIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Intent passWalletLaunchIntent = packageManager
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(strPackageName);
            if (null == passWalletLaunchIntent) {
                // PassWallet isn't installed, open Google Play:
                if (launchGooglePlay) {

                    String strReferrer = "";

                    try {
                        strReferrer = "&referrer=" + URLEncoder.encode(uri.toString(), "UTF-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        strReferrer = "";
                    }

                    try {
                        startIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + strPackageName + strReferrer));
                        applicationContext.startActivity(startIntent);
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                        // Google Play not installed, open via website
                        startIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + strPackageName + strReferrer));
                        applicationContext.startActivity(startIntent);
                    }
                }
            } else {

                final String strClassName = "com.attidomobile.passwallet.activity.TicketDetailActivity";
                startIntent.setClassName(strPackageName, strClassName);
                startIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
                startIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.apple.pkpass");

                applicationContext.startActivity(startIntent);

                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And an example call is:

```
launchPassWallet(getApplicationContext(),Uri.parse("http://test.attidomobile.com/PassWallet/Passes/AttidoMobile.pkpass"), true);
```

You can also use a file:// URL if you have the file locally.

To display them in the list, you'd need to unzip the .pkpass file and then parse the JSON for the relevant fields.

Comment: And a question: how to add a list passes? Now only can add 1 pass per 1 time.