# Add multi passes to wallet

Tags: android, passbook, passkit

I use mWallet/Pass2U Wallet  application to store passes.

Now I have several passes (form server returned) and I want to  to add a list passes to mWallet/Pass2U Wallet at the same time. Now only can add 1 pass per 1 time using this answer [Integrating and working with .pkpass passes in Xamarin Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25243333/integrating-and-working-with-pkpass-passes-in-xamarin-android-app)

Thanks in advance

Comment: All of these apps are provided by third party developers.  You would be better to contact the developer directly.  They may or may not have a feature to add multiple passes.

Comment: Yes, I am asking for the support from mWallet and Pass2U  app. Thanks for advice.